# How do I Reposition a Button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How do I fix this part of my program to relocate the button to a new location on the screen?

```
movingbutton1 = Button(root, text = 'Click Me' ... ).place(relx = .5, rely = .5)
time.sleep(3)
movingbutton1(root, text = 'Click Me' ... ).place(relx = .3, rely = .3)
```

Comment: Please refrain from vandalizing your own post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move a widget which was placed, you can use `place_configure(relx=new_x, rely=new_y)`.

To move a button when the user clicks on it, pass a function that moves this button to the `command` option of the button.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def move():
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    moving_button.place_configure(relx=x, rely=y)

root = tk.Tk()

moving_button = tk.Button(root, text='Click Me', command=move)

moving_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.after` method to move your widget after certain amount of time as shown:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(parent, text = 'Click Me')
        self.button1.place(relx = .5, rely = .5)
        self.button1.after(3000, self._moveButton) # Call method after 3 secs

    def _moveButton(self):
        # reposition button 
        self.button1 .place(relx = .3, rely = .3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('500x200')
    app = App(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is that you want

```
movingbutton1 = Button(root, text = 'Click Me' ... )
movingbutton1.place(relx = .5, rely = .5)
time.sleep(3)
movingbutton1.place(relx = .3, rely = .3)
```